# Vim/other editors bulk editing

Tags: vim, editor

I've got this sample list:
`cat 
dog
lion`

And this code in which i need insert it to:
`<li><img src="images/opcje/{value}.png" alt=""/><label for="wezel">{value}</label><input type="checkbox" id="wezel" {if strstr($opcje,"-{order_number}-")} checked {/if} name="opcje[]" value="-{order_number}-"/></li>`

And example output:
`<li><img src="images/opcje/cat.png" alt=""/><label for="wezel">cat</label><input type="checkbox" id="wezel" {if strstr($opcje,"-1-")} checked {/if} name="opcje[]" value="-1-"/></li>`
Is there any fast and DRY method for this?

Comment: vim's more for interactive editing. You'd want to use sed and/or awk for something like this - assuming you're reading the cat/dog/lion stuff from a file to begin with.

Comment: Yes, i can read it from file. Could you post some example?

Comment: I answered with an example macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a macro. It would work something like the following:

1. `vim my.xml`
2. `:sp` to split the window
3. `C-w j` to go to the bottom window
4. `:e mylist.txt`

Now you have both files open. Let's make a macro!

1. `qa` to record the 'a' macro
2. `dw` to delete the first list item
3. `C-w k` to go to the top window
4. `1G` to go to the beginning of my.xml
5. `/\{value\}` and press return to find the first instance of `{value}`
6. `P` to past before `{value}`
7. `wd7l` to jump to `{value}` and delete it
8. `C-w j` to jump to the bottom window
9. `q` to end recording macro

Now invoke your macro several times. For a 10-item list, try:

`10@a`

Voila!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in vim using a macro. You would start recording your macro by pressing `q` followed by some key, into which the macro would be saved. For instance `qa` would start recording the macro into key (or register) `a`. Then you would do the replacing once, but you must be sure to do it in such a way that if you execute the macro afterwards it will also work for the next word in your list. Press `q` again to stop recording. If you recorded your macro correctly, you can then execute the macro saved in register `a` by pressing `@a`, which would do the next replacement automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a small script like the following would be more appropriate:

```
#bash script
i=0;
for val in {cat,dog,lion}; do 
   i=$((i+1)); 
   sed -e "s/{value}/$val/g;s/{order_number}/$i/g" your_code > new_code_$i
done
```